# Can't change the appeareance of a certain link

Tags: css

on a certain website I would like to change the appearance of a certain link. The operator of said website did something to it so that it does not work the way it used to anymore.

(I'm moderately new to CSS, this much in advance.)

The link goes **[website]/internal/main.php?action=menu&id=[some number]**. So far I've been changing it with

```
a[href*="main.php?action=menu&id"] { font-size: 30px;}
```

but that does not work anymore. So basically 'select any link that cointains that string and change the fontsize to 30px'.

However it would be really helpful/convenient to be able to edit it. Any other links on the page can still be edited via the above CSS. After reading a little I thought adding "!important" would solve the problem, but it did not.

I was under the impression that no matter what the website 'does' that the user has full control over what the browser displays, as it should fetch the 'intended' thing from the server and THEN add custom CSS to it, effectively changing it.

To that end I've been using the Firefox AddOn "Stylus" to edit/change the appearance. Other similar programs also did not manage to change said links. (Stylish, StyleBot for Chrome). It is the same issue on both Chrome and Firefox. I have not tried any other browsers but i imagine it is the same there.

I'd be very thankful for any pointers in the right direction, explanations of where my understanding of the matter is wrong and/or solutions to this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The first step is to locate what styles are being applied and what is overriding yours. Use the Developer Tools in the browser of your choice (F12 in most cases) to inspect the element and see what is applied and what is overridden. You can also check if your style sheet has been downloaded and make sure to refresh your cache as the style sheet is cached. You may have a [speceficity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the original CSS definition for links on tha site is done for the different states `a:link`, `a:hover`, `a:active` and `a:visited`

So you should change your rule to

```
a:link[href*="main.php?action=menu&id"],
a:visited[href*="main.php?action=menu&id"] { font-size: 30px;}
```

And similar for the two other states

Comment: Unfortunately defining it this way did not change anything, as it is still in it's original size

Comment: well, you'll have to use the browser tools to find out which CSS rule (especially which selector) applies to the links, and then add a more *specific*  rule to your stylesheet to overwrite the original rule/s.

Comment: So I did that... "<a style="transform: scale(1, 1) !important; font-size: inherit !important" href=" ... and as far as Google takes me that is not possible to overwrite in CSS alone... Thank you